# How to find a positive solution to an under-determined linear system (if such a solution exists)?

Tags: linear-algebra, na.numerical-analysis, linear-programming

Like the title says, if an under-determined system of linear equations does have at least one positive solution, how to find it efficiently?

Suppose we have an under-determined system:

$$Ax = b$$

where $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $m < n$. How can we get a solution such that $x>0$?

I have tried to solve the system using **linear programming**: for the $Ax=b$ constraint, it is hard to find any solution. So I make it:

$$Ax \leq 1.01 b$$
$$Ax \geq 0.99 b$$

such that we have an approximated solution. But still had no success. To make a **proper objective function** is very tricky.

I wonder if there is some effective method to solve this problem?

---

btw: some papers might be relevant are listed:

> Conditions for a unique non-negative solution to an underdetermined
> system. http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5394815/
>
> A Unique "Nonnegative" Solution to an Underdetermined System: from
> Vectors to Matrices https://arxiv.org/abs/1003.4778
>
> The Farkas-Minkowski Theorem: [www.math.udel.edu/~angell/Opt/farkas.pdf](http://www.math.udel.edu/%7Eangell/Opt/farkas.pdf)

**Update 1:**

By using linear least-squares to minimize $\|Ax-b\|_2$ and $x \geq 0$, it seems that we can get non-negative solution $x$, nevertheless, the zeros in $x$ and the error of $A x$ to $b$ are still not acceptable.

**Update 2:**

Problem solved! Now I can get a positive solution perfectly meets the equations (1 - 10), even N is big, e.g. N = 1000 unknowns.

Comment: I see you already solved the problem, but in case this is helpful: what I usually do is add an extra variable $z$ and inequalities of the form $m_i \ge z$ and set the objective to maximize $z$.

Comment: You did it with linear programming? In this case, you are setting low bound to z? I did it as well, but no success :(. Also, can you please give some explanation on how you put z in A, and constructed the objective function? thanks

Comment: Yes, I use a LP solver. You can set a lower bound for z, but not necessary. If the optimal solution of the modified LP has $z\le0$, that means the original linear system has no positive solution. How you modify the problem to introduce the extra variable and extra inequalities depends on your LP solver. Good luck.

Comment: If you've solved the problem, KOF, let me encourage you to post the solution.

Comment: A relevant question: https://mathoverflow.net/q/262985/7076

Comment: @GerryMyerson well, by generating a random set of `x` such that error of `Ax` to `b` is within 10~20%, then use this set as starting point: we have better chance to get a new `x` such that the error is much lower.

Comment: can you describe in more detail how you solved that question? I am dealing with the same problem now. Thank you!

Comment: @Zhen Please check this paper: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10035-019-0874-x and the section "Mechanical properties of generated clumps
" .